# specific category address show same thing that show in homepage

Tags: wordpress, categories

I have a blog with several category that each category have some posts. with a WP_Query($args) in **index.php** I show posts in home page. it's ok.

```
$args = array(
    'cat' => -22,
);
$recent = new WP_Query($args); while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();?>
```

but my problem is that in category links like **http://www.example.com/category/cat1/**contents is same of homepage content.

I am search for the problems.
 **note: I want to remove cat = 22 in index and categories**

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying that when you go to category page like *http://www.example.com/category/cat1/ the page is the same as when you go to the home page?

If this is so, you are missing `category.php` template in your theme.

Example from [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) about Template Heirarchy:

> If your blog is at http://example.com/blog/ and a visitor clicks on a
>   link to a category page like
>   http://example.com/blog/category/your-cat/: Here is the progression of
>   how WordPress uses the template hierarchy to find and generate the
>   right file.
>
> WordPress looks for a template file in the current Theme's directory
>   that matches the category's ID.
>
> ```
> If the category's ID is 4, WordPress looks for a template file named category-4.php.
> If it is missing, WordPress next looks for a generic category template file, category.php.
> If this file does not exist either, WordPress looks for a generic archive template, archive.php.
> If it is missing as well, WordPress falls back on the main Theme template file, index.php.
> ```

You could create a category template by using code from default Twenty Twelwe theme in Wordpress.
Just go to **Dashoard > Appearance > Editor**, select that theme and copy the code from  category.php

Comment: It's in my mind that that in a link like http://example.com/blog/category/your-cat/ even we don't have category.php must only content of this category would be shown

Comment: That is what the code in category.php does. It shows posts of specific category.

Comment: My mentality is for my experience. When I haven't single.php http://example.com/?p=1346 shows 1 item

Comment: I found this chart useful showing how WordPress chooses its templates: http://codex.wordpress.org/File:Template_Hierarchy.png